# Deleting item RxSwift MVVM pattern

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift

Hi have a tableview with sections and I am making API call to populate the tableView. I am also using the MVVm architecture. Now users are able to delete items but I try reloading the sections or tableView but nothing happens as the deleted item still remains in the tableView. Below is my code. Any help is appreciated

**My ViewModel**

```
Observable.zip(identiferElements, deviceElements).map {(identifers, devices, _) -> [MyInfoSection] in
            var items: [MyInfoSection] = []
            let identiferRepository = identifers.map({ (repository) -> MyInfoSectionItem in
                let cellViewModel = IdentifiersCellViewModel(with: repository)
                return MyInfoSectionItem.identifiersItem(viewModel: cellViewModel)
            })
            if identiferRepository.isNotEmpty {
                items.append(MyInfoSection.setting(title: "Identifier", items: identiferRepository))
            }

            let deviceRepository = devices.map({ (repository) -> MyInfoSectionItem in
                let cellViewModel = DevicesCellViewModel(with: repository)
                return MyInfoSectionItem.devicesItem(viewModel: cellViewModel)
            })
            if deviceRepository.isNotEmpty {
                items.append(MyInfoSection.setting(title: "Active Devices", items: deviceRepository))
            }
            return items
        }.bind(to: elements).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag) 

deletedEvent.drive(onNext: { (item) in

            switch item {
            case .identifiersItem(let viewModel):
                identiferDeleted.onNext(viewModel.repository)
            case .devicesItem(let viewModel):
                deviceDeleted.onNext(viewModel.repository)
            }
        }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)

        identiferDeleted.asObservable().flatMapLatest({ [weak self] (value) -> Observable<ResponseBase> in
            log(value)
            guard let self = self, let id = value.id else { return Observable.just(ResponseBase()) }
            return self.provider.deleteAddress(id: id)
                .trackActivity(self.loading)
                .trackError(self.error)
        }).subscribe(onNext: { (res) in
            log(res)

        }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
```

**ViewController**

```
//viewDidLoad

let input = MyInfoViewModel.Input(trigger: refresh, segmentSelection: segmentSelected, selection: tableView.rx.modelSelected(MyInfoSectionItem.self).asDriver(), deleted: tableView.rx.modelDeleted(MyInfoSectionItem.self).asDriver())
        let output = viewModel.transform(input: input)
```

More code would be added based on request. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `combineLatest` instead of `zip`. The user can only delete an item out of one section at a time and zip waits until *both* sections emit a new value before emitting. There might be other problems, but that is one for sure.

I would need to see compilable code for your view model to help further.

Comment: Okay @Daniel T. Can I share a gist to show the view model?

Comment: I have created a gist https://gist.github.com/AdieOlami/9725ba8f9bd8482c6406e5bf1a6a9e60 you can view the View Model there

Comment: Either delete the unnecessary parts that don't compile or add code to make it compile.